# Show button above the map in a fragment in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

i am using a slidemenu with fragments. In one fragment I want to show a map with current location. This works perfectly. Now I want to insert buttons above to filter for certain things on the map. I looked at several sources that describe this, but all without the variant of fragments. It shows the buttons briefly and then the map covers the buttons. What I have already tried:
android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout"
into the fragment block, but then the map doesn't come up at all.
android:layout_weight="1"
in the fragment block, but that doesn't change anything.
Hope someone has a solution for this.
Thanks a lot
Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".MapsFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/map_restaurant_button"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_restaurant_24">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/map_bar_button"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_local_bar_24">
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I have already tried:
android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout"
into the fragment block, but then the map doesn't come up at all.
android:layout_weight="1"
in the fragment block, but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Take your LinearLayout's height as wrap_content and add android:layout_above="@+id/map" to LinearLayout, also remove android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout" from map fragment if added.
    Hope it helps.
    Try below code...
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".MapsFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

       <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/map_restaurant_button"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_restaurant_24">

     <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/map_bar_button"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_local_bar_24">
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. unfortunately, this change has brought no effect. The map is still visible in full size and the buttons are not there.

Comment: I have edited my answer with xml code try with it.

Comment: Thank you. With this it works now. error was so only wrap content